# What is boot-repair telling me to do here

Tags: boot, uefi, boot-repair

I'm examining boot-repair to "maybe" fix a problem I'm having with my machine booting to a black screen with just a cursor.

I have another post on the many, many things I've tried, and found a post on using boot repair.   So I booted from a live-usb and installed boot-repair and ran it.  I didn't select to repair but just to generate a report.  At the end of the report it is telling me something about BIOS-compatibility mode and to disable it.  It is also telling me something about UEFI I don't understand.

Here is the paste bin:   https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/4PWKQyc97q/

Comment: No, Boot Repair is NOT for that.

Comment: In the body of your question, can you copy/paste the exact term(s) that you are asking about?

Comment: What it says at the end is basic, trivial, stuff about boot modes (UEFI vs. BIOS/Legacy). And yes, you should disable CSM (Legacy) and assure all OSes are installed in UEFI mode. UEFI replaced BIOS some 10 years ago. Disabling CSM assures the live media boots in UEFI mode as it should be. However, it's IRRELEVANT for this case. Boot Repair is ONLY to (re-)install Grub. If Grub works whatever happens after Grub is not Grub's fault and CAN'T be corrected by Boot Repair.

Comment: I think that Boot Repair is telling you that you do not have GRUB on `/dev/nvme1n1` but Windows Vista is on `/dev/sdb` Boot repair is used to repair/reinstall/update GRUB, not for anything else. Make sure that you are installing UEFI OSes on a UEFI BIOS and EFI on an EFI BIOS. Also make sure that "Legacy Boot", "Secure Boot", or "Fast Boot" is turned off and disabled.

Comment: OK.. Thank you!   There is no obvious way I can see to mark this answered, but it is answered and very clear.  Thanks ChanganAuto!